# Error when i tried loading my windows phone 8 app to navigate to another page

Tags: c#

It takes me to the App.xaml page each time I run it. It then shows the error below:

```
// Code to execute if a navigation fails
private void RootFrame_NavigationFailed(object sender, NavigationFailedEventArgs e)
{
    if (Debugger.IsAttached)
    {
        // A navigation has failed; break into the debugger
        Debugger.Break();
    }
```

Comment: Do you have an example of an link you're navigating to?

Comment: Can you pinpoint where in your code this failure handling code is invoked and post *that* code?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have mentioned the target page's uri correctly. It should be like: **/folder_name_if_used/page_name.xaml**

Example:

NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/NewPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));

Suppose if NewPage.xaml is inside a folder called Views then it would be like this:
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Views/NewPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));

For more information look at this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff626521(v=vs.105).aspx)